# How to call a bool on click of a button

Tags: c#, events, onclick, boolean

I would like to insert or call a boolean function on click of a button.

Supposedly, this is the bool:

```
private bool IsCritical(int ProductID, int Quantity, int Available, int Criticallevel){
    bool existing = true;

    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.CriticalLevel, Products.Available, OrderDetails.Quantity FROM Products, OrderDetails WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid", ProductID);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productid",ProductID);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(Available < Quantity)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        int currentQty = Available - Quantity;
        if(currentQty >= Criticallevel)

        {
            return false;
        }
    else return true;
    }

    cn.Close();

    return existing;
}
```

but I cannot find a way to call it.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/AddToCart.aspx?ID=" + 
    Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + 
    "&qty=" + txtQty.Text);
}
```

Quantity corresponds to the amount of one product that the Customer bought.
Quantity should be lower or equal to the Critical Level.

What I want to happen is that when I click the Add button, the bool will run. If the Quantity is lower than or equal to the critical level, the program should proceed with the "Response.Redirect" in the Add_Click event. If not, an error message should show that the critical level has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Change ProductID, Quantity, Available, Criticallevel to actual values
    if (!IsCritical(ProductID, Quantity, Available, Criticallevel))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/AddToCart.aspx?ID=" + 
        Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + 
        "&qty=" + txtQty.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        //Write error message here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

But, may I know what you mean by "actual values"?

Comment: i don't know what is the value you're passing for the method IsCritical, that's why you need to change to what value you're actual passing.